# Excel named range as index

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using this formula:

```
=INDEX(Listings!$A$2:$X$4915,MATCH(H1,Listings!$B$2:$B$4915,0),14)
```

I want the Index array to be a named range, like so:

```
=INDEX(myRange1,MATCH(H1,myRange2,0),14)
```

When I try this, I get a #ref error.  Ranges are set to same array as listed in the first formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... I just did exactly what you mentioned and it worked just fine... Did you define the names correctly??? If you try and navigate to that range, does it work??

Comment: at first I had the same error, then I checked my named-ranges, had to correct one, because a `$` was missing. Then it worked.

Comment: I went back and traced the ranges.  Sure enough, they weren't being tied to the correct pages.

Answer (score 0):

Row_num, column_num, and area_num must point to a cell within reference; otherwise, INDEX returns the #REF! error value. If row_num and column_num are omitted, INDEX returns the area in reference specified by area_num.

[reference site](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/index-HP005209138.aspx)

Comment: Right, but putting in a named range should specify those values.

Comment: Hello Tim sorry got disconnected. Glad you got it fixed.